# Apply css value using JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to edit `css` values using `JavaScript/JQuery`. I have a `variable` I created, and I want to assign it like this:

```
var amount = 200;
$("p").css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": "amount%"}); // 200%
```

It only applies the color, not the font-size. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qpwt9t0f/), and here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        
        var amount = 200;
        $("p").css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": "amount%"});
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p style="background-color:#ff0000">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p style="background-color:#00ff00">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p style="background-color:#0000ff">This is a paragraph.</p>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button>Set background-color of p</button>

</body>
```

Comment: Change `"amount%"` to `amount + "%"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this `"amount%"` will be string with "amount%" value. but what you want is `amount + "%"` that changed to `200%`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        
        var amount = 200;
        $("p").css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": amount+"%"});
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p style="background-color:#ff0000">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p style="background-color:#00ff00">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p style="background-color:#0000ff">This is a paragraph.</p>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button>Set background-color of p</button>

</body>
```

Comment: When should I use `'$'`?

Comment: I really dont get whats you mean, but $  is function name of jQuery, when you want to select and find some things in your document you use it, it return the jQuery objecy.